# Apigee fault handling for CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE

Tags: apigee

In Apigee, can fault handling - specifying a FaultRule and a RaiseFault policy be used to handle and provide a custom message for:

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Not Found",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE"
        }
    }
}
```

If this can be done, should the 'Condition' for the fault rule be 'fault.name = "CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE"'? I tried this and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE is a system level failure to find an API Proxy for the given URL/URI. The request will not even reach the API proxy(hence the policies) - which is the precise complaint by the system.
So you do not want to handle an error like that.

Another way to approach this case is to have a catch all API proxy with basepath `/**` which will be invoked when there is no specific URL match. You can generate a custom message in this proxy - this can be the message you wanted to send across in case of classification failure.

Comment: Thank you for this reply and the suggestion regarding a catch-all API Proxy, which I could implement and set to a custom response with the AssignMessage policy.

Answer (score 0):

Srikanth's answer on 30/05/2014 is only partially correct. Using a basepath /** did not work for us. Instead, we had to create an api proxy with basepath = /

Inside the proxy, we defined a RaiseFault in Preflow and that was it.