# Apigee proxy SSL CLASSIFICATION_FAILURE 404 vs. 301 REDIRECT

Tags: apigee

When I have an API that only accepts HTTPS and I make an HTTP request the default seems to be a 404 error.  Is there a way to automatically redirect to the HTTPS URL?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is with a conditional RaiseFault policy.

Here's a simple example of

The RaiseFault policy looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RaiseFault async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="301tossl">
<DisplayName>301toSSL</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
<FaultResponse>
    <Set>
        <Headers>
          <Header name="Location">https://{request.header.host}{request.uri}</Header>
      </Headers>
        <Payload contentType="text/plain">SSL Required.
        </Payload>
        <StatusCode>301</StatusCode>
        <ReasonPhrase>Moved Permanently</ReasonPhrase>
    </Set>
</FaultResponse>
<IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</RaiseFault>
```

And the here's an example of putting a condition on the policy (in the preflow in this case):

```
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
    <Request>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>301tossl</Name>
            <Condition>client.scheme = "http"</Condition>
        </Step>
    </Request>
    <Response/>
</PreFlow>
```

I've got a sample here if you want to download ->
 https://github.com/carloseberhardt/edge-samples/tree/master/proxies/301ssl

Answer (score 0):

I would go with similar approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944470/apigee-fault-handling-for-classification-failure/23945626#23945626) of catch all and redirect. Catch all proxy always redirects. You need not raise a fault, you can do it in response flow of catch all proxy.